# VB net & Mongo: Using where clause with LINQ causes error "Unsupported where clause: (Boolean)Operators.CompareObjectLess"

Tags: vb.net, mongodb, linq, where-clause

I have a collection in MongoDB and I'm using MongoDB Driver in VB net. I want to update several documents depending on a condition.
For this, I want to use LINQ, but the select causes an error and I don't know how to fix it.

Here's the code:

```
Dim update_for As UpdateBuilder
Dim query_for As IMongoQuery
Dim coll_for = db.GetCollection(Of MyClass)("collection_1")
Dim queryMun = (From a In coll_for _
                Where (a.field_1 < 10000) _
                Select a)

For Each emp In queryMun
    query_for = Query.EQ("_id", emp.Id)
    update_for = Update.Set("field_1", BsonValue.Create("0" + emp.field_1))
    coll.Update(query_for, update_for, opts)
Next
```

When it executes de For Each sentence, it raises the exception: ***Unsupported where clause: (Boolean)Operators.CompareObjectLess(a.field_1, 10000, true).***

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to do this update based on the value of the attribute itself. What I want to do is add a "0" at the beginning of the attribute value, for example, if field_1=4567, after the update field_1='04567'.

Here's the code:

```
Dim update_for As UpdateBuilder
Dim query_for As IMongoQuery
Dim opts = New MongoUpdateOptions
opts.Flags = UpdateFlags.Multi
Dim coll_for = db.GetCollection(Of MyLINQClass)("collection_1")

Dim queryMun2 As New QueryDocument
Dim query_1 = Query.LT("field_1", MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue.Create(10000))
queryMun2.AddRange(query_1.ToBsonDocument)

Dim queryMun = coll_for.Find(queryMun2)

For Each emp In queryMun
    query_for = Query.EQ("_id", emp.Id)
    update_for = Update.Set("field_1", BsonValue.Create("0" + emp.FField_1.ToString))
    coll.Update(query_for, update_for, opts)
Next
```

And here is the definition of MyLINQClass:

```
Public Class MyLINQClass
    <BsonElementAttribute("_id")> _
    Public Property Id() As ObjectId

    <BsonElementAttribute("field_1")> _
    Public Property FField_1() As Object
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is clear:

You can't use a Less Than "<" operator in you WHERE clause because it's unsupported.

Comment: Thank you @Oscar. And how can I do the less comparation? Is it possible?

Comment: @Aliena I'm not a mongo specialist, you should read the docs. But it seams that lt "<" operator is supported with another syntax:  https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/csharp/query/#specify-conditions-with-operators

Comment: Thank you @Oscar, but this is for MongoDB directly. I need to run it in VB net. What I've found in the MongoDB website is in C#, and it uses the < operator. I can do simple queries with Query.EQ, Query.LT, etc, but I need to iterate through a query result, and then update the data adding a "0" in front of the value that the attribute has. It's not an update with a fixed value, is conditioned for the value that it's already in the attribute.